# How to globally change Wordpress default sorting order from default if custom field value exists

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I am sorting posts from a custom field of 'movies'. I have a field value in the 'movies' custom field called 'sorting'. I've added this code to the loop of the template where I am displaying 'movies' to sort the posts according to the 'sorting' values:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => ‘movies’, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'sorting'  ) ); ?>
```

I am trying to check, globally (because I need this sorting on multiple pages with no template), if this custom field value exists, that posts are sorted according to the meta_key value 'sorting' as they are in the template. Can I add a function to the functions.php file to check if this exists and if it does to sort all posts this way like I am in the template?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function sorting_by($query) {
  if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sorting', true)) {
     $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
     $query->set('meta_key', 'sorting');
     $query->set('order', 'ASC');
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sorting_by');
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot test if the meta_value exists, as you're dealing with the query and NOT with each post that this query will retrieve.

You'd better be sure to set this sorting value to all your posts if you want to make it work on pages with no template. If you plan to do it, consider to replace this by a 'post type' test, and you'll avoid to set those parameters to other post types :

Check if the current post type is 'movies' :

```
if( $query->get('post_type') == 'movies' ) {
    //$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num'); // Use this if 'sorting' is numeric.
    $query->set('meta_key', 'sorting');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right that makes sense worked perfectly. Thank you!